# Spring data - two one to many relationships

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

is there a way to have one entity (ex. Place ) bounded with another entity (ex. order ) where there are two "places" source and destination ?

example code :

```
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "SOURCE_ID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Place source;

@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "DESTINATION_IDs")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Place destination;
```

What will be on the Place entity?

Comment: **If** you make the two associations bidirectional, then there will be two OneToMany associations. But I don't think a place should know about the orders that start from it, or arrive to it. So I wouldn't make those bidirectional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work without a problem just like single relations. There is no difference. This includes making the relationship bidirectional, although I'm almost always skeptical about bidirectional relationships.